# System not booting to USB. I want to install dual install Windows alongside presently Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running. I want to install Windows 10 alongside.

Whenever I boot my system, it opens the Grub menu (which only lists Ubuntu and memory test) and does not boot from Removable Disk.
What am I doing incorrectly?

I flashed the Win10 iso file using "WoeUSB" to a removable disk (pen drive). Then, went to change the boot order.

My boot order:

1. Removable Disk
2. W3... (hard disk)
3. TSST-CORP...(cd drive)

I also have partitions set up.

```
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  46.4G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 120.5G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 105.2G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  19.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1   7.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   7.3G  0 part /media/amey/Windows USB
└─sdb2   8:18   1   512K  0 part /media/amey/UEFI_NTFS
```

Ubuntu is installed on `sda5`.

I am trying to install Windows 10 to `sda1` which has a partition type of NTFS/exFAT/HPFS (Bootable).

Here `sdb` is my removable disk and the parts `Windows USB` and `UEFI_NTFS` were created by WoeUSB.

Edit: The win10 iso is official and not corrupted.

Comment: Maybe boot a Windows 10 iso file and check that

Comment: @ HyperCreeck how to do that?

Comment: That the boot order is not taken into account indicates that the removable is not considered a bootable alternative according to the BIOS. I too have failed with woeusb. Make a new windows bootable directly from a windows machine.

Comment: Hey! You are looking on the Grub menu, which only shows installed oses, not USB devices. when you boot, click <kbd>DEL</kbd> button. And then boot into Windows 10 installer. This is not a problem with GRUB.

Comment: @HyperCreeck Pressing DEL takes me to CMOS setup (this is where I set the boot order)

Comment: Never mind the boot order, try to bypass it by diretcly choosing (in BIOS) which device to boot from.

Comment: @Serafim I did some changes in Boot menu and now the Windows 10 logo pops up on booting. Unfortunately, it is now stuck at a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Comment: I still think that you need to make a better USB by using Windows USB/DVD Download Tool from a computer running windows.

Comment: @Serafim Yes, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a Windows system to create a bootable USB with the "Media Creation Tool" from the official Windows website.
This question is closed here.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution.